# Xpages - How do I find the id of a component on my page?

Tags: xpages

I'm getting lots of errors in my openLog db:

> Expression Language Interpret Exception Error:'compositeData' not
>   found - Error on _id773:
>
> Interpret exception
>
> Error:'compositeData' not found

Multiple times, with a different ID each time. If I view source and search for any of the ID's I can't find them anywhere.... I'm now getting tunnel vision! Is there anything that jumps out to give a hint in direction? The error I assume if because I'm referencing a compositeData property somewhere that doesn't exist, but I have so many custom properties with loads of custom controls so finding it hard to pinpoint. Even if someone can see in the stack trace a field type, or something it will help me narrow it down. Thanks

**Stack trace:**

> Stack Trace com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Interpret exception at
>   com.paulwithers.openLog.OpenLogErrorHolder.getInterpretException(OpenLogErrorHolder.java:114)
>   at
>   com.paulwithers.openLog.OpenLogErrorHolder.addError(OpenLogErrorHolder.java:216)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:322)
>   at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpretCatch(ASTTry.java:150) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:113) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
>   at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:686)
>   at
>   com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
>   at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
>   at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:194)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspOutputLabel.getFor(XspOutputLabel.java:158)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:1863)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl.applyProperties(StyleKitImpl.java:391)
>   at com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl.applyStyle(StyleKitImpl.java:240)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:196)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl._applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.stylekit.StyleKitImpl.applyStyles(StyleKitImpl.java:192)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.applyStyles(ViewHandlerEx.java:137)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:93)
>   at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:250)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
>   at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:159) at
>   com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138) at
>   com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:588)
>   at
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:865)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:808)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:577)
>   at
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
>   at
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
>   at
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
>   at
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
>   Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Error:'compositeData' not found at
>   com.paulwithers.openLog.OpenLogErrorHolder.getInterpretException(OpenLogErrorHolder.java:113)
>   ... 67 more

Comment: Its in a value binding of a Label.

Comment: Thanks Sven, gives me somewhere to start! I'll feedback later with some positive news hopefully!

Comment: Sven, your answer helped me find the issue prior to Paul's response but he submitted his as an answer and I cant accept a comment as an answer but just to let you know that pointer was very much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sven says, the line including `com.ibm.xsp.component` is the one to check for, in this case `com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspOutputLabel.getFor(XspOutputLabel.java:158) at`. This actually should give you plenty of information to fix the problem. `XspOutputLabel` means it's a label component - look at the built Java classes in Package Explorer in the `local` folder and you'll see what Java classes get created for an XPage (choose a simple XPage!). The `get....` bit also tells you which property the error is being triggered for, in this case `getFor` means it's the `for` property. The error says it's failing in a computation to set `compositeData`. So look for a Label that has a computed `for` property that uses `compositeData`.

Typically, if you're getting a vague "_id...." it means the component doesn't have the `id` attribute set, so just `<xp:label value="My Label"></xp:label>` instead of `<xp:label id="myLabel" value="My Label"></xp:label>`.

Comment: I've found the issue! It was where I was trying to compute the target control ID. Not sure why it was causing an issue looking at my code, but at least now I know where the issue is I can resolve. Thanks both try{
 var fieldName:string=compositeData.fieldName;
 var fieldLabel:string=compositeData.radio1LabelText;
 return "radioGroup"+fieldName+fieldLabel; 
}catch(e){
 openLogBean.addError(e,this.getParent());
}

Answer (score 3):

Next time, you can do the following:

**Create a Java class "JavaScriptDebugBindingFactory"**

```
package ch.hasselba.xpages;

import com.ibm.xsp.binding.BindingFactory;
import com.ibm.xsp.util.ValueBindingUtil;
import javax.faces.application.Application;
import javax.faces.el.MethodBinding;
import javax.faces.el.ValueBinding;

public class JavaScriptDebugBindingFactory implements BindingFactory {
    public static final String JAVASCRIPT = "javascript";

    public String getPrefix() {
        return "javascript";
    }

    public MethodBinding createMethodBinding(Application app, String str,
            Class[] arr) {
        String tmpStr = ValueBindingUtil.parseSimpleExpression(str);
        return new JavaScriptDebugMethodBinding(tmpStr, arr);
    }

    public ValueBinding createValueBinding(Application app, String str) {
        String tmpSttr = ValueBindingUtil.parseSimpleExpression(str);
        return new JavaScriptDebugValueBinding(tmpStr);
    }
}
```

**Add the MethodBinding class**

```
package ch.hasselba.xpages;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.el.EvaluationException;
import javax.faces.el.MethodNotFoundException;

import com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding;
import com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx;

public class JavaScriptDebugMethodBinding extends JavaScriptMethodBinding {

    public JavaScriptDebugMethodBinding() {
        super(null, null);
    }

    public JavaScriptDebugMethodBinding(String str,
            Class[] arr) {
        super(str, arr);
    }

    public Object invoke(FacesContext fc, Object[] obj)
            throws EvaluationException, MethodNotFoundException {
        UIComponent cmp = getComponent();
        try {
            return super.invoke(fc, obj);
        } catch (EvaluationExceptionEx e) {
            System.out.println("COMPONENT: " + cmp.getId());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

**Add class JavaScriptDebugValueBinding**

```
package ch.hasselba.xpages;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.el.EvaluationException;
import javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException;

import com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding;
import com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx;

public class JavaScriptDebugValueBinding extends JavaScriptValueBinding {

    public JavaScriptDebugValueBinding() {
        super();
    }

    public JavaScriptDebugValueBinding(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    public Object getValue(FacesContext fc) throws EvaluationException,
            PropertyNotFoundException {
        UIComponent cmp = getComponent();
        try {
            return super.getValue(fc);
        } catch (EvaluationExceptionEx e) {
            System.out.println("COMPONENT: " + cmp.getId());
            throw e;

        }
    }
}
```

**Overwrite the JavaScript Handler in beforePageLoad**

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:
        importPackage( ch.hasselba.xpages );
        var facts = facesContext.getApplication().getFactoryLookup();
        facts.setFactory("javascript", new ch.hasselba.xpages.JavaScriptDebugBindingFactory())

    }]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

When an error oocurs, the id of the component is printed to the server console.

Comment: Cheers Sven, have to admit, I'm yet to do much with Java as my knowledge is lacking in that area but I understand I really should learn it sooner rather than later!